# Does using Redux in a Meteor application double the client side memory requirements?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, redux

I've been building a system with Meteor, and ReactJS. I recently added Redux into the application mostly because dispatching actions throughout the application was much easier to manage.

But I've hit a snag that I had not considered.

I use `Task.autorun` to subscribe to record sets. When the records change I dispatch an action passing along the data and into the store.

But now I have 2 client side collections containing the same data right? One in the minimongo client side database, and the other in the state.

If that's the case is it possible have minimongo not store the data clientside and only listen for changes on the data?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your data payload at runtime? Since browser tabs use several hundred MB of memory these days, your client side data might be insignificant compared to that.